# Avoiding frequent call to same view inside a Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, view

I have a oracle view it returns 5 million records from different tables and i use this view to insert into different tables using a single procedure, inside this procedure i use this several times and this is affecting the performance, is there any way we can query the view once and later i can use it multiple places?

Comment: GTT is always helpful but you need to find out the root cause of the performance issue. Using view number of times is not an issue but how you filter could be the issue. I hope with each individual usage you do access with different criteria and whether for those index used or not ? When we cannot do any sort of tuning with minimal structure changes to the tables I would go for GTT.

Comment: Sujith, we cannot do any structural changes at this point, i hope following GTT is give  better that querying same views in the same procedure multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is a stored query; itself, it doesn't contain any data. If its code is complex and fetches data from several tables, using different conditions, aggregations, whatnot, it can take some time to access data.

In your situation, maybe a global (or private; depending on Oracle version you use) temporary table (GTT) would help.

- you create it once
- at the beginning of the procedure, insert data from the view into it
- the rest of the procedure would work with those *prepared* data
- once the session (or transaction; depending on how you set the GTT up) is over, data from the table is lost

  - the table can be reused next time you run the procedure

Comment: Thanks Litle foot it has 50 lakh data is it advisable to store in temp tables? i hope this will increase preformance as it query only one table every time here after..

Comment: You're welcome. As I said: if fetching data takes time, this approach might help. If a view was simple enough and returned not that many data, you could use only it (a view) all the time. Try the GTT, index it properly, see how it behaves.