# Avoid using same view multiple times inside oracle procedures

Tags: oracle, view, procedure

I am using a view named V_ENT_MSG in my oracle procedure "TEST PROC" as shown below. The same view is used in multiple places inside the procedure and the procedure execution time is very high. The view returns more than 5 Million records every time. How can I improve procedure execution time. [ Note that I cannot change the view V_ENT_MSG].

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "TESTPROC"
AS
BEGIN  
  INSERT
  INTO OUTBOUND1
    (
      DELIVERY_EVENT_ID,
      MESSAGE_ID      
    )
     SELECT 
     V2.DELIVERY_EVENT_ID,PS.MESSAGE_ID     
     FROM V_ENT_MSG V2,
     R_SOURCE PS        
     WHERE V2.primary_source = PS.SOURCE;     
  COMMIT;
  
  INSERT
  INTO OUTBOUND2
    (
      DELIVERY_EVENT_ID,
      MESSAGE_BODY      
    )
     SELECT 
     V2.DELIVERY_EVENT_ID,PS2.MESSAGE_BODY     
     FROM V_ENT_MSG V2,
     R_SOURCE2 PS2        
     WHERE V2.primary_source = PS2.SOURCE;     
  COMMIT;
  
  INSERT
  INTO OUTBOUND3
    (
      DELIVERY_EVENT_ID,
      SUBJECT      
    )
     SELECT 
     V2.DELIVERY_EVENT_ID,PS3.SUBJECT     
     FROM V_ENT_MSG V2,
     R_SOURCE3 PS3     
     WHERE V2.primary_source = PS3.SOURCE;     
  COMMIT;
END TESTPROC;
```

Comment: What about approach I suggested yesterday? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572321/avoiding-frequent-call-to-same-view-inside-a-oracle-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to rewrite this as a multitable insert. To do this, you need to:

- (Outer) join the view to each table
- `insert all` the result of this query
- Use the `when` clause to control which rows go in which tables

Which looks something like:

```
insert all

  when ps.source is not null then
    into outbound1 ( delivery_event_id, message_id )
    values ( delivery_event_id, message_id )

  when ps2.source is not null then
    into outbound2 ( delivery_event_id, message_body )
    values ( delivery_event_id, message_body )

  when ps3.source is not null then
    into outbound3 ( delivery_event_id, subject )
    values ( delivery_event_id, subject )

select v.delivery_event_id,ps3.subject     
from   v_ent_msg v
left join r_source ps     
on     v.primary_source = ps.source
left join r_source2 ps2     
on     v.primary_source = ps2.source
left join r_source3 ps3     
on     v.primary_source = ps3.source;
```

This assumes that each `primary_source` joins to at most one row in `r_sourceX`. If it's 1:M and each value of `primary_source` can join to a different number of rows in each of the other tables it gets trickier.

You'll need to assign a `row_number` for each source value in each `r_sourceX` table and only insert those rows where this is one.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally whether you have opted for GTT as suggested by @Littlefoot or not ,you can still use this approach.

How about leveraging  `INSERT ALL` with `WITH` clause to achieve the same ,

```
INSERT ALL  
  /* inserting to OUTBOUND1 based on table_name = R_SOURCE defined during union */ 
  WHEN table_name = 'R_SOURCE' THEN
    INTO outbound1(delivery_event_id, message_id) 
    VALUES(delivery_event_id, message_type) 
  /* inserting to OUTBOUND2 based on table_name = R_SOURCE2 defined during union */ 
  WHEN table_name = 'R_SOURCE2' THEN 
    INTO outbound2(delivery_event_id, message_body) 
    VALUES (delivery_event_id, message_type) 
  /* inserting to OUTBOUND3 based on table_name = R_SOURC3 defined during union */ 
  WHEN table_name = 'R_SOURCE3' THEN 
    INTO outbound3(delivery_event_id, subject) 
    VALUES (delivery_event_id, message_type)
WITH ent_msg
AS
(SELECT v2.delivery_event_id,v2.primary_source
    FROM v_ent_msg v2),
src_data 
AS 
( SELECT v2.delivery_event_id delivery_event_id,ps.message_id message_type,'R_SOURCE' table_name
    FROM r_source ps
    JOIN ent_msg v2
      ON v2.primary_source = ps.source
  UNION ALL
  SELECT v2.delivery_event_id,ps2.message_body,'R_SOURCE2' table_name
    FROM r_source2 ps2
    JOIN ent_msg v2
      ON v2.primary_source = ps2.source
  UNION ALL
  SELECT v2.delivery_event_id,ps3.subject,'R_SOURCE3' table_name
    FROM r_source3 ps3 
    JOIN ent_msg v2
      ON v2.primary_source = ps3.source
)
SELECT delivery_event_id,message_type,table_name
  FROM src_data
```

I couldn't validate SQL because of tables are missing.

There are other ways too in case of performance issue where we can go for `BULK COLLECT` with `LIMIT`. I am not aware of the data set you are dealing with.

Hope this guides you proceeding with your question.

Comment: Can we use bulk collect as  like temp tables? in select query where clauses??

Comment: @ Vinod.T.V: I get your point. Did the above query work ? As I said if you have performance issue we can go for bulk insert or GTT. What exactly now you need?

Comment: Multiple insert needed to different values with the help of values from the views these tables are entirely different. The view fetch the records from multiple table everytime more than 5M records that is causing this slowness. Which I am trying to avoid.